# How do I display an image after pressing an UI button in unity3d?

Tags: c#, javascript, unity

I am working on a game in unity3d in which I want to display the details about the players when a button is being pressed.
Suppose there are 12 players so for that I will have to make 12 UI buttons as well and I have done that too but the problem is that how to display image after clicking the buttons?
If anyone knows please sort out my problem, any help would be more appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why did u mark as duplicate? Still m stuck with this problem please help me out if you know something related to this..!